# css insert text instead of image

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Instead of image how to include a text saying required

```
    <label class="req">Name:</label>
    .req
    {
       //background-image:url(img/mandatory.jpg);
       background-position:top right;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       padding-right:10px;
      font-weight:bold;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the background image at all, remove it, and use the `:after` pseudo-element to insert the text:

```
.req:after {
    content: '*';
}
```

If you need the background image as a fallback for older browsers (because IE7 and older don't recognize `:after`), you'll have to resort to some CSS hack or something to apply it for older browsers (or just put the background image in a separate stylesheet with a conditional comment).